# Passing objects between multiple python scripts

Tags: python

This is difficult to briefly explain. I'm trying to create a set of python scripts, that together make up a single selenium test case.  So the first script would login to the website.  The next script would take off where the first script left the page, and create a new user.  The third would log out.

Since you need to use the same webdriver object for each browser instance, I need a way to pass the webdriver object from script to script, without using script arguments.  The reason is because I'm actually writing these python scripts as osx automator actions, and the only way to provide input to the script, is via StdIn. So each action can't just return the webdriver object for the next action/script to accept and use.  If I try returning the webdriver object to the next script, it just returns ''

I thought there might be a chance I could pickle the webdriver object to a file, and have the subsequent script load it and then use it, but when I try to pickle the webdriver object, I get an error about not being able to pickle a file object.  (I'm not super experienced with Python)  So that was a bust.

I know this is a confusing question, but does anyone know a valid way to pass objects from one script to another, accounting for the constraints I've mentioned?  Would sockets work by any chance? Or am I just trying to do something that can't reasonably be done?

If I can just nail down this one problem, it seems this project could work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python supports pipes between programs, but it may only be good for text streams.

Comment: A pipe, by definition, is only good for text streams. OP could do by pickling... if the object was pickable, but you can only pickle/marshal/whatever you want to call it objects whose internal state can be represented in a static way in terms of Python, and this is not the case for true "file" objects, I'm afraid. And this is not a problem inherent to Python. You cannot pickle things that depend on internal state held by a 3rd party (the operating system, a web server...)

Comment: "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea"

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier.  I thought I was going to get email updates.  I actually talked to some of the other developers at work today and ended up abandoning the project.  Creating test cases from Automator seemed like a cool idea, but only in theory it seems.  At least when using selenium.  I appreciate the time you took to respond everyone.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation btw Ricardo.  That's one of the questions I had yesterday as I thought this out. I'm basically a self taught junior developer, so explanations like that are always appreciated. I wasn't aware of the static nature of serialized objects until I started trying to do this, and suspected that must be the case.  Much appreciated.